# ssmtp in docker image

Tags: docker, sendmail, ssmtp

I'm trying to setup ssmtp (for sendmail) in Docker image.

To do so I've created the folowing Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

# Install paquet requirements
RUN set -ex; \
    # Install required system packages
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -qy --no-install-recommends \
            ssmtp \
            mailutils \
    ; \
    # Clean aptitude cache and tmp directory
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*;
```

As you can see I have installed ssmtp and mailutils.

My /etc/ssmtp.conf file contains all credentials that I can log into my account using standard mail client:

```
root=serwer@mydomain.com

mailhub=mail.mydomain.com:587
AuthUser=serwer@mydomain.com
AuthPass=PASS_HERE

FromLineOverride=YES

UseTLS=YES
#UseSTARTTLS=YES
Debug=YES

hostname=OVERRIDEN_HOSTNAME
```

From some reason mail is not sent. I'm tying with `sendmail` command:

```
sendmail my_email@example.com
Subject: aaa
aaa
CTRL+d
```

and getting error:

```
sendmail: Authorization failed (535 Incorrect authentication data)
```

Even `Debug=YES` is set, I do not see any log under `/var/log` regarding sendmail.

Do you have any thought what might be wrong?

Thank you all!

Comment: Is this really a programming question?

Comment: Hey @Vega. You might be right, I have started it as basic docker question, but seems problem statement might be rather related more with unix-like thing. Probably unix exchange is a better place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem. Issue was Windows line ending of ssmtp.conf file.

It explains why username was not correct and why `Debug` flag and `UseSTARTTLS` flag changes were not respected.

Many thanks to @telcoM for a way to debug server flow.